# what does while(~scanf mean in C?

Tags: c

i watch some code and i don't know what the meaning of `while(~scanf`

```
while(~scanf("%s", word+1) !=EOF)
{
    int a= strlen(word+1);
```

i already search google and found nothing on this. Please help

Comment: Run as long as the bitwise-inverted return value of `scanf` is not equal to the value of `EOF`.

Comment: Knowing what [`scanf` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value) might help. But I still think it doesn't make much sense with the bitwise complement `~`. Where did you see this code? What is the context?

Comment: And since: [We can move the `~` to the other side of the equation] AND [`EOF` is typically all 1s], this is equivalent to "run until `scanf` returns 0".

Comment: It assumes that `EOF` is `-1` and works as long as `scanf` returns `1`, which negated is `-2` in two's complement, which is not equal to `-1`. When `scanf` returns `0` it is `-1` after negation, which is NOT unequal `-1` so the loop stops. It's a misleading, needlessly complicated way of just writing `while(scanf("%s", word+1))` that also relies on a couple of assumptions for no good reason.

Comment: @goodvibration While that *does* make sense in a perverted kind of way, it raises more question though, like who the h*ll wrote code like that?

Comment: This code should be in the (yet to be created) Stack Overflow "Repository of Deliberately Dodgy Code!"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Good point, I have enclosed a variation of it in my answer.

Comment: And `strlen()` returns `size_t`, not `int`.  Someone who thought he was clever really isn't.

Comment: the meaning of "while(~scanf... != EOF) is that the person who wrote the code was either (a) writing for an obfuscated code challenge or (b) too clever for their own good or (c) had to obey a coding standard that required all I/O to explicitly check for EOF (or any combination thereof)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analyzing the expression `while(~scanf("%s", word+1) != EOF)`:

> Run as long as the bitwise-inverted return value of `scanf` is not equal to the value of `EOF`.

Analyzing the equivalent expression `while(scanf("%s", word+1) != ~EOF)`:

> Run as long as the return value of `scanf` is not equal to the bitwise-inverted value of `EOF`.

Assuming that `EOF` is typically all 1s, this expression is essentially equivalent to:

`while(scanf("%s", word+1) != 0)`

Which means:

> Run as long as the return value of `scanf` is not `0`.

Or simply:

> Run until the return value of `scanf` is `0`.

I'm still scratching my head as to whether or not this analysis is correct.

Good question for a job interview (and a good example for how to not write code).

Answer (score 0):

On success scanf will return the number of input items successfully matched. In this case there is only one input item to match therefore on success scanf will return 1, The code above will bitwise invert 1 which will make it -2. Since -2 != EOF, the loop will not end. Since EOF has a value of -1.

If scanf encounters an error or reaches end of input, for example because the user pressed Ctrl-D, it will return EOF and no new value will be placed in the memory location word+1. The code will bitwise invert EOF, which becomes 0, because ~EOF=0. Since 0 != EOF the loop will not end. The call to strlen will return the length of string that was in memory location word+1 prior to calling scanf.

The loop will only end if scanf returns 0, because ~0 = -1 = EOF. This will only happen if scanf was unable to match the input to a string for the conversion specifier "%s".